# Infinite try even after multi fatal error occurs

Tags: php, function, shutdown

I'm developing a content management system (CMS) and i have a serious problem in plugin (and module) manager right now!
each plugin may have many syntax or logical errors, so this CMS core must handle every errors even fatal error by himself. 
i tried to use `register_shutdown_function("self::resume");` before each plugin load and if any error happens, skip corrupted plugin and continue to load others.
but problem is when a fatal error occurs, `register_shutdown_function` execute resume function once, but if next fatal error happens, PHP finished current process even a new shutdown function defined before last error!

so is there any trick to keep alive this scripts even many fatal error occurred?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to say, especially near the end.  Can you try and make it a bit clearer?

Comment: register_shutdown_function works fine after an error occurs, but if another fatal error occurs after this function has been executed, php force stop this script. so i'm locking for a way to handle many fatal errors and prevent script from dieing!

Comment: I don't think you can do that (via this function) - the register_shurdown function is called on shutdown.  I mean when the script is already shutting down.  Its purpose is to do some graceful exit, really.  I reckon you should try to handle errors, instead.    Look into set_error_handler() and set_exception_handler()

Comment: wrap the plugin load and execute code in try .. catch statement. That should give you control of the errors from the plugins. Alas, i think that will not stop PHP parse errors and compile errors from being fatal. note to self: I need to read the instructions again.